# Push Notification With Background Task (ios)

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I implemented Remote Push notifications for my app. I can receive Push notifications just fine.

However my goal is to execute some code automatically when Remote Notification Arrives on my iphone.

For example i have a Google Nest mini Speaker. I would like to send Push notifications to my iPhone, which should trigger a "Audio Playback" on my Google mini speaker.

I got it to work, only if user TAPS the Notification Banner, however I would like to automate it, whether user taps the notification banner or not.

I have the same exact logic working on Android, however for ios i am having issues when it comes to handle push notification.

So Question is, it it even possible to receive a remove notification and trigger something automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow this guide: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

It is called Background Push Notification or Slient Push Notification.

But System will **limit the number of times that your app can run in background** to execute some codes.